# Responsive images enlarge when moving their parent parent div absolute left

Tags: css

I have a div with responsive images inside like so:

```
<div class="collection" style="" id="content">
<div class="collection row">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col4.jpg"></div>      
  </div> <!-- end .row -->

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col4.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col2.jpg"></div>      
  </div> <!-- end .row -->

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col4.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/col1.jpg"></div>      
  </div> <!-- end .row -->

</div>
</div>
```

The `#content` div is absolutely positioned with a left `value` of `0`.

IF i keep decrementing its value by 10px, the images keep enlarging up to a certain point (in this case it waits untill left has a value of `300px`) before the whole div actually starts moving left.

Why doesn't the whole div just normally move left in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I found your issue. Just change this:

```
<div class="collection" style="" id="content">
<div class="collection row">
```

to this:

```
<div class="collection" style="" id="content">
<div class="collection container">
```